# Django translations not showing from app's po

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n

I've been developing an application which works in English or French (Canadian). Django settings are;

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fr-ca', gettext('Canadian French')),
]
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    ...
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'console', 'locale'),
    ...
)
```

The app's locale path is `console/locale/fr-CA/LC_MESSAGES/`

The app however has recently stopped rendering the vast majority of the translations, while django debug toolbar, and other apps are displaying French without issue.

For example, I've got a form with 'First name', 'Last name', 'Email'. Yesterday this was correctly using the po file;

```
#: console/forms/participants.py:631
msgid "First Name"
msgstr "Prénom"

#: console/forms/participants.py:635
msgid "Last Name"
msgstr "Nom"

#: console/forms/participants.py:140 console/forms/participants.py:469
#: console/forms/participants.py:639 console/models/mixins.py:70
msgid "Email"
msgstr "Courriel"
```

But today, only the `Email` string is appearing in French. I assume `ugettext` is getting that from another application because I've tested it in the shell;

```
>>> from django.utils.translation import ugettext, activate
>>> activate('fr-ca')
>>> ugettext('Sunday')
u'dimanche'
>>> ugettext('Event')
u'Event'
>>> ugettext('Yes')
u'Oui'
>>> ugettext('Gender')
u'Gender'
>>> ugettext('enquiry')
u'enquiry'
>>> ugettext('Enquiry')
u'Enquiry'
>>> ugettext('Receive notifications about other events.')
u'Receive notifications about other events.'
```

These are all taken from the app's po file;

```
#: console/models/events.py:35 console/models/events.py:206
#: console/models/participants.py:81 console/models/vouchers.py:14
msgid "Event"
msgstr "Événement"

#: console/models/participants.py:113
msgid "Gender"
msgstr "Sexe"

#: console/models/participants.py:160
msgid "Receive notifications about other events."
msgstr "Recevez des notifications pour un événement."
```

It goes without saying I've ran the translation management commands (and can see the locale paths being output);

```
manage.py makemessages -l fr-CA
manage.py compilemessages -l fr-CA
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should remember that `ugettext_lazy` is a lazy evaluation and should be used in models and forms (as they load only once in Django) for views you should use `gettext`
- Try delete (backup) translation files and recreate them again
- Check templates for existence of translation blocks

Comment: The majority of things are from models & forms using ugettext_lazy along with template translations. It'd be great to get an idea of what translation file a string comes from. Would help see where the things that are being translated come from.